# SocketActivityTrigger with reason SocketClosed

Tags: windows-runtime, uwp, windows-10-universal

maybe I found a bug in socket behaviour. If mobile data is ON and wifi is connected, after 10 minutes, SocketActivityTrigger backgroundtask is fired with reason SocketClosed. This only happens, when both internet types are ON. When only wifi is connected, KeepAliveExpired is the reason of SocketActivityTrigger. The same scenario if mobile internet is ON. So my question is, is it a bug or normal behaviour, that SocketClosed is the reason, when both internet types are ON?
Thank you

Comment: Are you saying that your server is also deployed on internet, not on LAN? I tested in LAN network, it works fine.

Comment: Server is public. I can connect to it through wifi and mobile internet. Problem is, when both wifi and mobile internet are turn ON. But I didn't mention server. I have app which has backgroundtask of type SocketActivityTrigger.

Comment: You mean when the mobile is not connected to server, the problem still happens?

Comment: Let me explain it. I have communication app (chat, calls). When I start the app, I log in to our server. Within login operation I create backgroundtask of type SocketActivityTrigger. When I close the app, I transfer the socket to the system. So I can receive SocketActivity, KeepAliveExpired, SocketClosed. When app is closed and mobile has wifi and mobile internet, after 10 minutes I receive SocketClosed. If only wifi or only mobile interne is ON, I receive KeepAlive. But If both are ON I receive SocketClosed.